# subquery Count() - Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just wanted to know, why a subquery returned more than one value, so I made this query:

```
SELECT id, 
    (SELECT Count(tags[i]) 
        FROM generate_subscripts(tags, 1) AS i 
        WHERE tags[i]='oneway') as oneway_string 

    FROM planet_osm_ways 
    WHERE 'oneway' = ANY(tags) 
    HAVING 
        (SELECT Count(tags[i]) 
            FROM generate_subscripts(tags, 1) AS i 
            WHERE tags[i]='oneway')  > 1
```

which should find all occurences of 'oneway' in `tags` array and count them.

```
[42803] ERROR: column "planet_osm_ways.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause 
               or be used in an aggregate function Position: 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `HAVING` to `WHERE` as there are no groups on which you could apply `HAVING` filter, instead you want to use `WHERE` filter which applies to each row.

```
SELECT id, 
(SELECT Count(tags[i]) 
    FROM generate_subscripts(tags, 1) AS i 
    WHERE tags[i]='oneway') as oneway_string 

FROM planet_osm_ways 
WHERE 'oneway' = ANY(tags) 
    AND 
    (SELECT Count(tags[i]) 
        FROM generate_subscripts(tags, 1) AS i 
        WHERE tags[i]='oneway')  > 1
```